# MFP 7.1 - How to use Oracle database for development environment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How can I use Oracle database for development environment? The reason I want to do that because I want to reproduce the issue we found in Test environment with push notification, - (users gets unsubscribed atomically when restarts the app.  User ID automatically gets overwritten by some code in PUSH_SUBSCRIPTION table.)

Derby which come with dev does not allow 2 connections.

Do I need to install the server or can I just point to existing oracle database where I already have WLADMIN and WRKLIGHT schema created.

Comment: You mention - "User ID automatically gets overwritten by some code in PUSH_SUBSCRIPTION table."
Are you noticing the issue only on iOS?

Comment: in both IOS and ANDROID

Comment: Specially when I restart the App. I guess the WL.Client.connect does that.

Comment: I just posted question regarding this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071561/mfp7-1-push-notification-user-id-gets-overwritten-by-some-code-on-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the development environment does support Oracle.

Open the your-project\server\conf\worklight.properties.
In this file there is the following section:

```
############################################
#   DB Settings [Development Only]
############################################

# For MySQL
#wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/WRKLGHT
# For Derby
#wl.db.url=jdbc:derby:${worklight.home}/derby/WorklightDB;create=true
#wl.reports.db.url=jdbc:derby:${worklight.home}/derby/WorklightReportsDB;create=true
# For DB2
#wl.db.url=jdbc:db2:WRKLGHT
# For Oracle
#wl.db.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID

#wl.db.username=worklight
#wl.db.password=worklight
```

Uncomment the line for Oracle (`wl.db.url`) and the `wl.db.username` and `wl.db.password` lines.

Fill in these lines with the correct details.

The next start, before starting the server, is to ensure that the database is ready.

If you already have an existing server, it could work. But if you want to test properly you should probably have a clean one. Either way, *backup your database*.

Because you'll be testing this from Studio, **I think** that the database will be created automatically for you on server startup (unlike with external servers where you must do this on your own). You may need to create it anyway, though. You'll need to run the ant script to generate the various tables.

Comment: This worked but I also had to add the ojdbc.jar file to my runtime war file.

Comment: Since I switched worklight database to oracle, I have noticed that I am not able to run the app in browser any more. I see this error in browser. http://hostname/MyProject/authorization/v1/clients/preview] failure. state: 500, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

Comment: How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The MobileFirst Platform development environment doesn't support the use of external databases for the MobileFirst Platform runtime and administration services - you can only use the embedded Derby database.  If you change the server.xml in the development server to load the Oracle JDBC driver instead of the Derby driver, and change the datasources to use it (and point to existing databases with the database schemas already created and populated using the scripts we provide for the standalone server - since the development environment does not give you a way to do this manually), I can not think offhand of a reason it would not work - but I've never tried it personally, and it's completely unsupported, so if you run into a problem doing this we may not be able to offer you any help.  Also, I am not sure if your server.xml changes would get overwritten whenever you redeploy the application (i.e., the WAR file) to the development server.

Probably the easiest (and most supportable) way of accomplishing what you would like to do would be to set up a separate standalone test server using Oracle as the database server.

It would not be a good idea to point this test environment towards existing databases that are already being used for a production application; it should have its own databases that are separate from any other environment.

Comment: Thanks Pathbarron! I think to be safe I will create separate standalone server by running the ants scripts and add that server in eclipse without touching development server. so that I can switch back if required.

Comment: Based on the information Idan provided, my answer appears to be incorrect - I searched through the documentation for a way to do it, and couldn't find that...  Please try Idan's suggestion, and if you find that it resolves your question, please mark his answer as "Accepted" so this no longer shows as an unanswered question.  Thanks!